# What does "French" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In a novel called "Pattern Recognition" by William Gibson is the paragraph:

> Seated, not bothering with the menu, Cayce orders coffee, eggs, and sausage, all in her best bad French.
>
> The girl looks at her in amazed revulsion, as though Cayce were a cat bringing up a particularly repellant hairball.
>   "All right," says Cayce, under her breath, to the girl's receding back, "be French."

What does "be French" mean here?

Comment: Where did you get this sentence from?

Comment: A novel called "pattern recognition "by william gibson-page 83

Answer (score 14):

**More context would be useful.**  I see that the entire paragraph goes like this:

> Seated, not bothering with the menu, Cayce orders coffee, eggs, and
>   sausage, all in her best bad French.
>
> The girl looks at her in amazed
>   revulsion, as though Cayce were a cat bringing up a particularly
>   repellant hairball.
>
> "All right," says Cayce, under her breath, to the
>   girl's receding back, "be French."

Put briefly:

- Cayce orders breakfast in bad French
- The girl looks disgusted
- Cayce says "All right, be French."

**This is referring to a stereotype about French people, specifically, that they do not respect anyone who doesn't speak good French.**  The girl looks disgusted that Cayce is speaking bad French, and Cayce says, loosely, **"OK, then, obey the stereotype of French people if you want to."**